# Zeugma on a genitive noun: extraordinary or prosaic?

Tags: medieval-latin, genitive, figurae-sermonis

[This Reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/latin/comments/3y949z/sol_oritur_occasus_nesciuslyrics_in_comments/cybjulf/) points out that there is a [zeugma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeugma_and_syllepsis) on a genitive noun in this sentence from the [conductus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conductus) "Sol oritur occasus nescius"* in the [*Hortus Deliciarum*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hortus_deliciarum):

> Et **filiæ** fit pater filius

I'd never heard of such a thing: the single word **filiæ** modifies both the subject of the verb and the subject complement! Is this a poetic use of grammar, emphasizing what an odd thing it is for the deity to become His own son?

But then it occurred to me that you can do the same in English and the grammar doesn't seem remarkable:

> And the father **of the daughter** becomes the son.

So, is the zeugma on a genitive extraordinary in Latin? Are there other instances of it?

Or is it not a zeugma at all? Does **filiæ** modify only one of the nouns, as if it were written *Et pater filiæ fit filius*? Even the English "zeugma" could be read that way.

---

*<sub>Tangentially, there's a great [false relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_relation) (I think) in [this performance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mUx4-Eb7y6k) a couple lines later, on the *O* in *O pro populo.*</sub>

Comment: Sententia mea novacula Occami dictat genetivum a Filio referire, ut in _the father becomes the son of the daughter_. Mary being a daughter of God (as everyone else) became the mother of Jesus (God the Son, a different person but the same One God in mainstream Christian theology)