# Occasus nescius

Tags: medieval-latin, grammar-identification

In the first line of [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/latin/comments/3y949z/sol_oritur_occasus_nesciuslyrics_in_comments/cybjulf/) 12th-century [conductus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conductus):

> Sol oritur occasus nescius

what does [*nescius*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=nescius) refer to? Maybe diagramming the sentence is all I need, because I don't follow the grammar.

If the idea is that the Sun rises not knowing when or whether it will set, then I'd expect the sentence should be *Sol oritur occasum nesciens.* If the idea is that when the Sun rises, no one knows when or whether it will set, then I'd expect *Sol oritur occaso nescio* (although I think first of *nescio* as the verb "I don't know").

But the word is *occasus,* which could be a noun or an adjective. If a noun, that would tend to put it into a different case, as above. So maybe it's an adjective modifying *Sol.* But then what does the sentence mean—The Sun rises, having already set, without knowing how it rises? That *could* make sense, given that the rest of the poem runs through religious paradoxes involving a single thing appearing in two forms that somehow interact with each other. I don't know the idioms and grammar well enough to say.

Comment: Re: the context, Sol and filius seem to me to unambiguously refer to Jesus, Pater to God, Mater and (probably) filia to Mary. The second verse reminds me of Dante, Divine Comedy, Paradisio 33, 1: "Vergine madre, figlia del tuo figlio"

Comment: @Rafael Te [hanc quæstionem](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/11094/118) videre quæso.

Comment: Sol does not refer to the physical Sun. It refers to the person, the Son Jesus Christ, who rose from the grave and will never set (die) again. Not that hard to understand really.

Comment: @Pudy Rafael already mentioned that above. There's no need for additional rudeness.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To add a bit to Mitomino's excellent (and correct) answer:

Vowel length, so unhelpfully ignored in most Mediaeval manuscripts, is the key here.

> *Sōl orītur occās**ū**s nescius*

In other words, this is the genitive singular, not the nominative!

*Nescius*, like some other words referring to knowledge and memory, can take its topic in the genitive. That's what's happening here. The sun rises, ignorant **of its own setting**.

EDIT to add: it's not always clear whether an *-us* noun is second or fourth declension, especially one you haven't seen before. But when a noun is formed by putting *-us* on the supine stem, meaning "act of ___ing", the result is always in the fourth declension.

Comment: Ah, I think you've answered the question in my [comment to Mitomino](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/11119/occasus-nescius/11122#comment20560_11121).

Comment: [This page](https://www.millenniumofmusic.com/playlist/crown-veil-music-from-medieval-female-monasteries/) translates it "The Sun rises, the one that never sets." Could that be right— *nescius* meaning metonymically "it never happens" since what never happens is unknown?

Comment: @BenKovitz That's not a usage I've ever heard before, nor one that I can find in L&S, though it's entirely possible it came about later.

Comment: @Draconis: could the genitive of the present-participle, "occidentis", be used instead of "occasus"?

Comment: @tony Mm, I don't think so; if anything I might use a gerund, _occidendī_. _Occidentis_ would be more like "ignorant of the-thing-that-is-currently-setting", rather than "ignorant of the-action-of-setting".

Comment: @Draconis: The setting is in the future, of course it is; so, not pres. part. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Here the predicative adjective *nescius* is taken as governing **genitive** (*occasus*) rather than accusative (*occasum*). In fact, this is also found in Classical Latin: e.g., *nescia mens hominum fati sortisque futurae* (Verg. *Aen.* 10, 501). So notice that in your example *occasus* is to be analyzed as an **objective genitive** (in parallel with *fati sortisque futurae*, which is also objective genitive with *nescia*. NB: *hominum* is subjective genitive with *mens* in Vergil's example).

Comment: Tibi gratulor, quod iam mille puncta tulisti!

Comment: Ah, _occasus_ is fourth declension! Thanks, that straightens out the grammar—and this was my first encounter with _nescius._ One question remains, though: what does the sentence mean? Is it "The Sun rises, not knowing how to set?" Not knowing that setting even exists?

Comment: Draconis's answer might have it: "ignorant of its own setting".